# Wordpress - Saving data in DB

Tags: php, wordpress

How would you make this:

- you have a single input field in the site, asking for an email address (for ex. to subscribe for a newsletter)
- you would like to save the introduced data in DB (preferably in a new table) and you would like to show it in the admin area on a new page

What is the best way to do this? Is it worth making a plugin for this?
Every idea is appreciated!
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't make a new table, but rather save the data either in `wp_options` or, if you want to collect emails, just save them as a `custom post type` perhaps.

Anyhow, if you really want to use your own table, take a look at the [`$wpdb` global](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb), it offers an easy and safe way to interface with the database. First use the `prepare` method to create your query, and then execute it with the `query` method.

Answer (score 1):

use gravity forms. its one of the best plugins ever. http://www.gravityforms.com/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I would like to make it myself, to be implemented in my custom theme, preferably I would not use any big plugins with lot of extra function which I don't need.

Comment: I would define your custom functionality in a plugin. I kinda hate it when devs hide app logic in the theme. if you need help getting started: http://www.yaconiello.com/blog/how-to-write-wordpress-plugin/

Comment: When I will have enough reputations, I will give a +1 for the link. Until then I'll bookmark your blog :) Thanks!